# Correct document root with htaccess and subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to use subdomains with my engine PLUTO.
But I don't want to have twice engine files when it comes to subdomains.
My engine is using a router file and a htaccess file to redirect all links to this router file.

The problem:
When I use subdomains the htaccess file searches for the router file in the directory of the subdomain and not the directory of the htaccess file(which is in the previous folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /pluto.router.php
```

How do I tell the htaccess it should redirect to the pluto.router.php in the htaccess folder ?
or:
How do I find out/write the document_root for the htaccess ?

Edit:
I think I can't write http://www.example.com/pluto.router.php cause I use multiple domains.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you try something like this:

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.htmlhttp://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

And then of course the olddirectory/oldfile should be named your own and same goes for the newdirectory.